# Cannot npm install protagonist in OS X 10.9.5

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install protagonist in OS X via `npm install protagonist`. However, it fails as below.

Any idea?

```
$node -v
v0.11.13
$npm -v
1.4.9

$npm install protagonist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/protagonist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/protagonist

> protagonist@0.15.0 install /Users/Bruce/node_modules/protagonist
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/CBlueprint.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/CSourceAnnotation.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/HTTP.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/Section.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/Serialize.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/SerializeJSON.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/SerializeYAML.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/Signature.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/snowcrash.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/csnowcrash.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/UriTemplateParser.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/posix/RegexMatch.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/snowcrash.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libmarkdownparser/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/src/ByteBuffer.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libmarkdownparser/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/src/MarkdownNode.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libmarkdownparser/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/src/MarkdownParser.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/markdownparser.a
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libsundown/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/ext/sundown/src/autolink.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libsundown/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/ext/sundown/src/buffer.o
CC(target) Release/obj.target/libsundown/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/ext/sundown/src/markdown.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libsundown/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/ext/sundown/src/src_map.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libsundown/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/ext/sundown/src/stack.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libsundown/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/ext/sundown/html/houdini_href_e.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libsundown/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/ext/sundown/html/houdini_html_e.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libsundown/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/ext/sundown/html/html.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/libsundown/snowcrash/ext/markdown-parser/ext/sundown/html/html_smartypants.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/sundown.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/protagonist/src/annotation.o
In file included from ../src/annotation.cc:1:
../src/protagonist.h:11:36: error: expected class name
    class Blueprint : public node::ObjectWrap {
                                   ^
../src/protagonist.h:26:48: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
        static v8::Handle<v8::Value> New(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                               v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:149:7: note: 'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/annotation.cc:1:
../src/protagonist.h:33:43: error: expected class name
    class SourceAnnotation : public node::ObjectWrap {
                                          ^
../src/protagonist.h:45:48: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
        static v8::Handle<v8::Value> New(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                               v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:149:7: note: 'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/annotation.cc:1:
../src/protagonist.h:52:33: error: expected class name
    class Result : public node::ObjectWrap {
                                ^
../src/protagonist.h:66:48: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
        static v8::Handle<v8::Value> New(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                               v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:149:7: note: 'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
In file included from ../src/annotation.cc:1:
../src/protagonist.h:73:46: error: no type named 'Arguments' in namespace 'v8'; did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
    extern v8::Handle<v8::Value> Parse(const v8::Arguments& args);
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                             v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:149:7: note: 'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
../src/annotation.cc:19:17: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'v8::HandleScope'                                                  [52/1832]
    HandleScope scope;
                ^
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:845:13: note: declared protected here
  V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
            ^
../src/annotation.cc:21:55: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'v8::Isolate *' with an lvalue of type 'v8::Handle<v8::Value>
      (const v8::internal::Arguments &)'
    Local<FunctionTemplate> t = FunctionTemplate::New(New);
                                                      ^~~
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:3520:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'isolate' here
      Isolate* isolate,
               ^
../src/annotation.cc:23:29: error: no member named 'NewSymbol' in 'v8::String'
    t->SetClassName(String::NewSymbol("SourceAnnotation"));
                    ~~~~~~~~^
../src/annotation.cc:25:41: error: 'New' is a private member of 'v8::PersistentBase<v8::Function>'
    constructor = Persistent<Function>::New(t->GetFunction());
                                        ^
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:594:23: note: declared private here
  V8_INLINE static T* New(Isolate* isolate, T* that);
                      ^
../src/annotation.cc:25:61: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
    constructor = Persistent<Function>::New(t->GetFunction());
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                 ^
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:594:3: note: 'New' declared here
  V8_INLINE static T* New(Isolate* isolate, T* that);
  ^
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8config.h:312:20: note: expanded from macro 'V8_INLINE'
# define V8_INLINE inline __attribute__((always_inline))
                   ^
../src/annotation.cc:26:26: error: no member named 'NewSymbol' in 'v8::String'
    exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("SourceAnnotation"), constructor);
                 ~~~~~~~~^
../src/annotation.cc:29:43: error: unknown type name 'Arguments'; did you mean 'v8::internal::Arguments'?
Handle<Value> SourceAnnotation::New(const Arguments& args)
                                          ^~~~~~~~~
                                          v8::internal::Arguments
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:149:7: note: 'v8::internal::Arguments' declared here
class Arguments;
      ^
../src/annotation.cc:31:17: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'v8::HandleScope'
    HandleScope scope;
                ^
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:845:13: note: declared protected here
  V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
            ^
../src/annotation.cc:33:17: error: no member named 'Wrap' in 'protagonist::SourceAnnotation'
    annotation->Wrap(args.This());
    ~~~~~~~~~~  ^
../src/annotation.cc:33:26: error: member access into incomplete type 'const v8::internal::Arguments'
    annotation->Wrap(args.This());
                         ^
Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:149:7: note: forward declaration of 'v8::internal::Arguments'
class Arguments;
      ^
../src/annotation.cc:34:18: error: no member named 'Close' in 'v8::HandleScope'
    return scope.Close(args.This());
           ~~~~~ ^
../src/annotation.cc:34:28: error: member access into incomplete type 'const v8::internal::Arguments'
    return scope.Close(args.This());
                           ^
/Users/Bruce/.node-gyp/0.11.13/deps/v8/include/v8.h:149:7: note: forward declaration of 'v8::internal::Arguments'
class Arguments;
      ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/protagonist/src/annotation.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/Bruce/.nvm/v0.11.13/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/Users/Bruce/.nvm/v0.11.13/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Bruce/node_modules/protagonist
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.13
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! protagonist@0.15.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the protagonist@0.15.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the protagonist package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls protagonist
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "/Users/Bruce/.nvm/v0.11.13/bin/node" "/Users/Bruce/.nvm/v0.11.13/bin/npm" "install" "protagonist"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Bruce
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.13
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Bruce/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally the problem is that it only support node 0.10.

Switch the node version to 0.10 works.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else hits this issue later on, for me it was an issue of not accepting the xcode license (sinceI had that installed). So, to make it work,  follow these steps:

- run `sudo xcodebuild` in a terminal
- scroll through the license via 'space'
- type `accept`

Then, installing protagonist via the command should work:

`npm install protagonist`